# tikz text width causes error

Tags: errors, packages, pgfkeys

What am I doing wrong to have this error in my thesis report ?

The error:

```
./Chapter1.tex:666: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/width',
 to which you passed '12cm', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelle
d it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.666 ...t=5cm,node distance=5cm,fit=(A1)(B1)(C1)]
                                                  (container){};
?
```

The source code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[above]
\node[b,text width=3cm,below=3cm, node distance=2cm]at (6,7)(but){Mise à jour "But"};
\node[b,text width=3cm,below=3cm, node distance=2cm]at (-2,-8)(commande){Commande};
\node[b,text width=3cm,below=3cm, node distance=2cm]at (6,-8)(mise){Exécution des requêtes  et la mise à jour};
\path [l] (but.west) -| (-2,2.2);

\node[text width=6cm]at (0,2)(A0){Planificateur};
\node[c,text width=3cm]at (-4,1)(A){Fonctions de planification};
\node[c,text width=3cm,below=1cm] at (-4,1) (B){Gestionnaire "état/ressource"};
\node[c,text width=3cm] at (0,1)(C){Modélisation déclarative};
\node[c,text width=3cm,below=1cm] at (0,1)(D){Mise à jour "Etat/Activité"};
\node[c,text width=3cm,below=3cm]at (-2,1)(E){Envoi d'activité};
%%line 666 %%% \node[c,text width=12cm,minimum height=6cm,node distance=3cm,fit=(A)(B)(C)(D)(E)](container){ };
\vspace{2cm}
\node[text width=8cm]at (6,-2)(A01){ };
\node[c,text width=6cm, node distance=5cm]at (6,-2)(A1){Base de données "plan d'activité"};
\node[c,text width=6cm, node distance=5cm] at (6,-3) (B1){Synchronisation "Planificateur/B.D"};
\node[c,text width=6cm, node distance=5cm] at (6,-4)(C1){Exec "activité D.B"};
%%%\node[c,text width=3cm,below=1cm] at (8,-3)(D1){Mise à jour "Etat/Activité"};
%%%\node[c,text width=3cm,below=3cm]at (6,-3)(E1){Envoi d'activité};
\node[c,width=12cm,minimum height=5cm,node distance=5cm,fit=(A1)(B1)(C1)](container){};
\node[text width=6cm, node distance=2cm]at (0,-5)(A02){Exécutif TDL};
\node[c,text width=3cm,node distance=2cm]at (-4,-6)(A2){Modélisation procédurale};
\node[c,text width=3cm,below=1cm,node distance=2cm] at (-4,-6) (B2){Synchronisation des tâches};
\node[c,text width=3cm, node distance=2cm] at (0,-6)(C2){Mise à jour des tâches};
\node[c,text width=3cm,below=1cm, node distance=2cm] at (0,-6)(D2){Exception/Surv.. d'état};
\node[c,text width=3cm,below=3cm, node distance=2cm]at (-2,-6)(E2){Envoi d'activité};
\node[c,width=12cm,minimum height=6cm,node distance=4cm,fit=(A2)(B2)(C2)(D2)(E2)](container){};

\path [l] (E.south) -| (-2,-4.75);
\path [l] (1.75,1) -- (2,1);
\path [l] (2,1) |- (A1.west);
\path [l] (A1.west) -| (2,1);
\path[l](2,-4)|-(C2.east);
\path[l](2,-4)|-(2.75,-4);
\path[l](D.east)-|(2,-4);
\path[l] (E2.south)--(commande);
\path[l] (D2.east)-|(mise.north);
\path[l] (mise.north)|-(D2.east);
\path[l] (-6.5,1)|-(commande.west);
\path[l] (-6.5,1)|-(A.west);
%\draw[densely dashed] (-4,-12) -- (6,-12) node {c.fonctionnelle.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Architecture \ac{CLARAty}.}
\label{Architectureclaraty}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, isn't the error quite clear? You have used `width=12cm` in the `container` node, and not e.g. `text width` as in the other nodes.

Comment: Actually this happened twice.

Comment: Thanks, It was working fine, i have just deleted `width=..cm` in all tikz pictures

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.